# Probability and statistics(numbers inside a bowl)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So, inside a bowl there are numbers from 0 to 9 (0,1,2....,9). If you take out 3 random numbers without putting the number back after each extraction, and compose a number by those 3 digits in extraction order, what is the probability that the number is divisible by 12?

I don't quite know how to solve this problem, can you guys please explain it ?
Thank you .

PS: numbers can't start with '0'.

Comment: How many total numbers can you create this way? How many of them are divisible by 12? For instance, you can't create 144 this way, as the digits must be distinct.

Comment: right, so there aren't 73 3-digit numbers, I counted the digit-repeating ones also..

Comment: There might very well be 73 3-digit numbers divisible by 12, but not all of them are able to be created this way. Check the ones with distinct digits, then divide that by the total number of numbers you can produce this way. How many possible numbers can you create this way?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you could form 12 this way. 012 is a perfectly acceptable sequence.

Comment: well that's exactly what I am asking, I don't know how to calculate how many I can create this way because the digit '0' is kind of in the way, I don't know how to exclude it.

Comment: If a number can't start with 0, there are $9*9*8 = 648$ possible choices for sequences, i.e. you have 9 choices for the first digit (anything but 0), 9 choices for the second digit (anything but the first choice), and 8 choices for the final digit (anything but the previous 2).

Comment: So then now we must see how many numbers from the range 102-987 are divisible by 12 AND do not have repeated digits, then you simply take that as the numerator and the 648 as the denominator.

Comment: oh yeah, I see now, so if say after extracting a number out of the bowl, the number gets back in the bowl for the next extraction we would have 9*10*10(first 9 is because we don't allow 0, and then we can have any number we want, even if they are repeating), right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: amazing, I now understand, thank you so much, you can submit it as an answer and I will accept your answer :)

Comment: Looks like @A.D beat me to it. The important thing is that you understand.

Comment: yeah but I will accept yours, because you made it clear to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your favorable cases are $108,120,132,156,168,180,192,204,216,240,264,276,312,324,348,360,372,384,396,408,420,432,456,468,480,492,504,516,528,540,564,576,612,624,648,672,684,708,720,732,756,768,780,792,804,816,840,852,864,876,912,924,936,948,960,972,984$.

And total no of cases are $9\times 9 \times 8 =648$

Now, use classical definition of probability.